# Почему появилась ошибка AttributeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Вот ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'an_class' object has no attribute 'on_off'

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QScrollArea, QScrollBar, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QPainter, QPixmap

import os
import sys

import random

import linecache

import time

count_max = random.randint(3, 10)

File_location_old = str(os.path.abspath(__file__))
File_location = File_location_old.replace("sentense.py", "")
count_question = 1
i = 0

#стартовое окно
class Ui_Start(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Start):
        Ui_Start.setObjectName("Ui_Start")
        Ui_Start.resize(443, 293)

        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 321, 51))
        self.lineEdit1.setStyleSheet("")
        self.lineEdit1.setText("")
        self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 421, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 210, 141, 58))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 321, 58))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Start)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Start)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Start):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Start.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Start", "Ui_Start"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Ui_Start", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
        "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Введите номер и букву класса:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "инструкция"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Найти класс"))

#инструкция        
class Ui_Inst(object):
    def setupUi(self, Inst):
        Inst.setObjectName("Ui_Inst")
        Inst.resize(1111, 883)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Inst)                        # (v) ???
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 1111, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.text_inctru = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Inst)
        self.text_inctru.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 1071, 811))
        self.text_inctru.setObjectName("text_inctru")

        self.retranslateUi(Inst)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Inst)                      # (v) ???

    def retranslateUi(self, Inst):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Inst.setWindowTitle(_translate("Inst", "Inst"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Inst", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
        "<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:22pt;\">Инструкция</span></p></body></html>"))        

#выбор ученика
class Ui_Uch(object):
    def setupUi(self, Uch):
        Uch.setObjectName("Uch")
        Uch.resize(718, 336)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLabel(Uch)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 611, 81))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit1")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Uch)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 140, 341, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Uch)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 222, 601, 61))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Uch)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 601, 41))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Molot\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Uch)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Uch)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Uch", "Uch"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Uch", "Выбрать ученика"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Uch", "Задать вопрос"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Uch", "Отвечает ученик:"))

#Окно ошибки
class Ui_och(object):
    def setupUi(self, och):
        och.setObjectName("och")
        och.resize(530, 221)
        och.setStyleSheet("QLaber{\n"
        "    font: 45pt \"Molot\";\n"
        "    backgroun-color: white;\n"
        "    width: 75px ;\n"
        "    height: 50px;\n"
        "    font-size: 45px;\n"
        "    font-weight: bold;\n"
        "    bolder: none;\n"
        "    text-align: center\n"
        "}\n"
        "\n"
        "")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(och)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 511, 81))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 45pt \"Molot\" ;")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_error = QtWidgets.QLabel(och)
        self.label_error.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 531, 121))
        self.label_error.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_error.setText("")
        self.label_error.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(och)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(och)

    def retranslateUi(self, och):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        och.setWindowTitle(_translate("och", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("och", "    ОШИБКА!!!"))

#Окно с вопросом    
class Ui_otv(object):
    def setupUi(self, otv):
        otv.setObjectName("otv")
        otv.resize(1114, 918)
        otv.setStyleSheet("font: 87 25pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_uch = QtWidgets.QLabel(otv)
        self.label_uch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1101, 61))
        self.label_uch.setStyleSheet("font: 87 25pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_uch.setObjectName("label_uch")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(otv)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 1091, 791))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(otv)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 880, 281, 31))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(otv)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 880, 161, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(otv)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 882, 181, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(otv)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 880, 181, 31))
        self.pushButton_1.setStyleSheet("font: 87 14pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton")


        self.retranslateUi(otv)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(otv)

    def retranslateUi(self, otv):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        otv.setWindowTitle(_translate("otv", "Form"))
        self.label_uch.setText(_translate("otv", "Ученик отвечает:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("otv", "Введите размер шрифта:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("otv", "Установить"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("otv", "Следующий вопрос"))





#класс: инструкция
class MyInst(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyInst, self).__init__()

        self.label = QLabel(self)                                                   # 1
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label.setText(open(File_location + "3_mate_files" + "\inst.txt").read())

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)                                        # 2
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.label)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scrollbar = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)                            # 3
        self.scrollbar.setMaximum(250)

        self.scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(self.sync_func)                         # 4

        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scrollbar)

    def sync_func(self):
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollbar.value() * 20)

class GifDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(GifDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            text="Пожалуйста, подождите, \nпрограмма запускается",
            font=QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        )
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.show_gif()
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_gif(self):
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(
            "C:/for cheacher/3_mate_files/load.gif",                
            parent=self
        )
        self.label2.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        self.show()
#Класс: ученики
class MyUch(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Uch):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyUch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

#Класс: ошибка
class Myoch(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_och):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Myoch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

#Класс: вопрос
class MyOtv(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_otv):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyOtv, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)  

        self.koefW_q = 1
        self.koefH_q = 1
        self.w = self.size().width()
        self.h = self.size().height()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):        
        width_q =  self.size().width()    
        height_q = self.size().height()  

        self.koefW_q = width_q / self.w
        self.koefH_q = height_q / self.h

        self.label_uch.setGeometry(10*self.koefW_q, 15*self.koefH_q, 1920*self.koefW_q, 61*self.koefH_q)
        self.label.setGeometry(10*self.koefW_q, 90*self.koefH_q, 1091*self.koefW_q, 791*self.koefH_q)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(300, 880*self.koefH_q, 161*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(470+(self.koefW_q*10), 880*self.koefH_q, 161*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(900*self.koefW_q, 880*self.koefH_q, 181*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(10*self.koefW_q, 880*self.koefH_q, 281*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)

#Класс: главное меню
class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.inst_f)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.opr)
        global on_off




    def keyPressEvent_Enter(self, Enter):
            if Enter.key() in [QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return]:
                self.opr()
    #открытие инструкции
    def inst_f(self):
        self.inst = MyInst()
        self.inst.show()
    #открытие окна с учеником
    def uch_f(self):
        self.uch = MyUch()
        self.uch.show()
        self.uch.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.class_list)
        self.uch.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.hgh)
        self.uch.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.questions)

#открытие ошибки
    def och_f(self):
        self.och = Myoch()
        self.och.show()            
    # Выбор ученика    
    def class_list(self):
        file = open(File_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt','r')
        count = 0
        for line in file:
            count+=1
        with open(File_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt','r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        global x      
        x = random.choice(lines)
        self.uch.lineEdit.setText(str(x))
    def otv_f(self):
        global x
        self.otv = MyOtv()
        self.otv.show()
        self.otv.label_uch.setText("Ученик отвечает:" + "  " + x)
        self.otv.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.edit_font_size)
        self.otv.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.questions)
    def edit_font_size(self):
        self.otv.label.setStyleSheet(f"font: {self.otv.lineEdit.text()}pt \"Arial Black\";")
    #проверка наличия файла  
    def opr(self):
        if self.lineEdit1.text() == "admin":
            self.animation()
        else:
            path = File_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt'
            try:
                file = open(path)
            except IOError as e:
                self.och_f()
                self.och.label_error.setText(" Не удалось найти файл по следуюшему пути :  \n " + " " + path)
            else:
                self.uch_f()  
    def hgh(self):
        self.otv_f()
    def questions(self):
        global count_question
        file_ques = File_location + "2_question/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt'
        f = open(file_ques)
        b = 0
        for line in f:
            b+=1  
        global lines_ques            
        lines_ques = linecache.getline(file_ques, count_question).replace("((П))", "\n")
        if count_question != b:  
            count_question = count_question + 1
        elif count_question == b:
            count_question = 0
        self.hgh
        self.otv.label.setText(str(lines_ques))
        self.otv.label.setWordWrap(True)



StyleSheet = '''
QPushButton {
   font: bold italic 16pt 'Comic Sans MS';
   background-color: silver;
   width: 75px ;
   height: 50px;
   border: none;
   text-align: center;
}
QPushButton:hover {
   background: #C9C0BB;
}            
QPushButton:pressed {
   background-color: blue;
}

'''
on_off = 0
class an_class(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(an_class, self).__init__()
        global on_off
    def an_start(self):
        if on_off == 0:
            on_off = on_off + 1
            self.animation()
    def animation(self):
        self.ma = Main()
        self.ma.setEnabled(False)
        self.an = GifDialog()
        self.an.show()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.an_window)
        self.timer.start()
        self.an_window()
    def an_window(self):
        global i
        global count_max

        if i < count_max:
            i+=1
        else:
            self.ma.setEnabled(True)
            self.an = GifDialog()
            self.an.hide()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
file = QtCore.QFile(File_location + "3_mate_files" + "\dark.qss")                              
file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())
w = Main()
w.show()
start_to_window = 0
if start_to_window == 0:
    an_start()
    start_to_window = start_to_window + 1
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.on_off = on_off `  ?

Comment: Потому что в классе `an_class` нет attribute `on_off`. Потому что глобальные переменные - это `ЗЛО`. Опубликуйте воспроизводимый пример и попробуем сделать это правильно.

Comment: S.Nick, пожалуйста, не пугайтесь. https://pastebin.com/UPVPcqPH

Comment: глобальной она будет, если определить ее в "начале" класса

Comment: Это мои попытки исправить эту ошибку. Оно так работает.

Comment: if self.on_off == 0: проверяет переменную класса on_off раньше, чем она выставлена, поэтому ошибка. Потрудитесь как-то инициализировать переменную, прежде чем проверять её значение. И непонятно ещё зачем вам глобальная переменная on_off, если вы её нигде не выставляете и не используете.

Answer (score 1):

Я не вникал в вашу логику, а постарался сделать чтобы ваш пример заработал без глобальных переменных.

Один момент, который я не понял зачем он я пропустил. Это метод `animation` класса `An_class`, который написан не правильно. Потом помыслите и сделаете, если он нужен.

**Подправьте или восстановите свой `File_location = ""`**

Обратите внимание, как при создании экземпляров передаются параметры:

```
w = Main(File_location)
self.an_class = An_class(self) 
self.inst = MyInst(self.File_location)
```

Я не трогал модули созданные в `QT Designer`.

---

```
import os
import sys
import random
import linecache
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QScrollArea, QScrollBar, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QPainter, QPixmap


#стартовое окно
class Ui_Start(object):
    ...

#инструкция        
class Ui_Inst(object):
    ...

#выбор ученика
class Ui_Uch(object):
    ...

#Окно ошибки
class Ui_och(object):
    ...

#Окно с вопросом    
class Ui_otv(object):
    ...    

#класс: инструкция
class MyInst(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, File_location):                               # + File_location
        super(MyInst, self).__init__()
        self.File_location = File_location                           # + self.File_location ...

        self.label = QLabel(self)                                                   
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label.setText(open(self.File_location + "3_mate_files" + "\inst.txt", encoding='utf-8').read())

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)                                        
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.label)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scrollbar = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)                            
        self.scrollbar.setMaximum(250)

        self.scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(self.sync_func)                         

        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.scrollbar)

    def sync_func(self):
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollbar.value() * 20)

# ??? 
class GifDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(GifDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            text="Пожалуйста, подождите, \nпрограмма запускается",
            font=QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        )
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.show_gif()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_gif(self):
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(
            "C:/for cheacher/3_mate_files/load.gif",                
            parent=self
        )
        self.label2.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        self.show()


#Класс: ученики
class MyUch(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Uch):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyUch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

#Класс: ошибка
class Myoch(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_och):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Myoch, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

#Класс: вопрос
class MyOtv(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_otv):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyOtv, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)  

        self.koefW_q = 1
        self.koefH_q = 1
        self.w = self.size().width()
        self.h = self.size().height()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):        
        width_q =  self.size().width()    
        height_q = self.size().height()  

        self.koefW_q = width_q / self.w
        self.koefH_q = height_q / self.h

        self.label_uch.setGeometry(10*self.koefW_q, 15*self.koefH_q, 1920*self.koefW_q, 61*self.koefH_q)
        self.label.setGeometry(10*self.koefW_q, 90*self.koefH_q, 1091*self.koefW_q, 791*self.koefH_q)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(300, 880*self.koefH_q, 161*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(470+(self.koefW_q*10), 880*self.koefH_q, 161*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(900*self.koefW_q, 880*self.koefH_q, 181*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(10*self.koefW_q, 880*self.koefH_q, 281*self.koefW_q, 31*self.koefH_q)


class An_class(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(An_class, self).__init__(parent)
#@
        self.parent = parent                     # +
        print(f'self.parent -> {self.parent}')   # ! если надо обратиться к атрибутам класса Main


#        global on_off
        self.on_off = 0                           # +
        self.i = 0                                # +
        self.x = ''                               # +

    def an_start(self):
        if self.on_off == 0:                      # self.
            self.on_off = self.on_off + 1

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
# я не понял, что это ????, поэтому в моем примере это не задействовано !!!        
#?            self.animation()                       # ????????????????????????????? 

    def animation(self):
        self.ma = Main()                            # НЕТ, Main уже создан !!!
        self.ma.setEnabled(False)
        self.an = GifDialog()
        self.an.show()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.an_window)
        self.timer.start()
        self.an_window()

    def an_window(self):
#        global i
#        global count_max
        count_max = random.randint(3, 10) # ?

        if self.i < count_max:
            self.i += 1
        else:
            self.ma.setEnabled(True)
            self.an = GifDialog()
            self.an.hide()
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            

### Класс: главное меню
class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):
    def __init__(self, File_location, parent=None):             # + File_location
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.File_location = File_location                      # + self.File_location
        print(f'self.File_location = `{self.File_location}`')

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.inst_f)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.opr)

# ?        global on_off
#+++        
        self.count_question = 1                                  # +++

        self.an_class = An_class(self)                           # self 
        start_to_window = 0                                      # +
        if start_to_window == 0:                                 # +
            self.an_class.an_start()                             # + self.an_class
            start_to_window = start_to_window + 1                # +

    def keyPressEvent_Enter(self, Enter):
            if Enter.key() in [QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return]:
                self.opr()

    #открытие инструкции
    def inst_f(self):
        self.inst = MyInst(self.File_location)
        self.inst.show()

    #открытие окна с учеником
    def uch_f(self):
        self.uch = MyUch()
        self.uch.show()
        self.uch.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.class_list)
        self.uch.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.hgh)
        self.uch.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.questions)

    #открытие ошибки
    def och_f(self):
        self.och = Myoch()
        self.och.show()   

    # Выбор ученика    
    def class_list(self):
        file = open(self.File_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt','r', encoding='utf-8')
        count = 0
        for line in file:
            count+=1
        with open(self.File_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

#        global x      
        self.x = random.choice(lines)                      # self.x

        self.uch.lineEdit.setText(str(self.x))

    def otv_f(self):
#        global x
        self.otv = MyOtv()
        self.otv.show()
        self.otv.label_uch.setText("Ученик отвечает:" + "  " + self.x)
        self.otv.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.edit_font_size)
        self.otv.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.questions)

    def edit_font_size(self):
        self.otv.label.setStyleSheet(f"font: {self.otv.lineEdit.text()}pt \"Arial Black\";")

    #проверка наличия файла  
    def opr(self):
        if self.lineEdit1.text() == "admin":
#            self.animation()                          # ????????????
            pass                                       # +
        else:
            path = self.File_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt'
            try:
                file = open(path, encoding='utf-8')
            except IOError as e:
                self.och_f()
                self.och.label_error.setText(" Не удалось найти файл по следуюшему пути :  \n " + " " + path)
            else:
                self.uch_f()  

    def hgh(self):
        self.otv_f()

    def questions(self):
#        global count_question
        file_ques = self.File_location + "2_question/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt'
        f = open(file_ques, encoding='utf-8')
        b = 0
        for line in f:
            b+=1  
#        global lines_ques            
        lines_ques = linecache.getline(file_ques, self.count_question).replace("((П))", "\n")
        if self.count_question != b:  
            self.count_question += 1                     # count_question + 1
        elif self.count_question == b:
            self.count_question = 0
        self.hgh
        self.otv.label.setText(str(lines_ques))
        self.otv.label.setWordWrap(True)


#on_off = 0
#count_max = random.randint(3, 10)
#count_question = 1
#i = 0

#File_location_old = str(os.path.abspath(__file__))
#File_location     = File_location_old.replace("sentense.py", "")

File_location = ""                     # <--- поставьте свой путь !!!


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                        
    file = QtCore.QFile(File_location + "3_mate_files" + "\dark.qss")                              
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())
    w = Main(File_location)
    w.show()

#    start_to_window = 0
#    if start_to_window == 0:
#        an_start()
#        start_to_window = start_to_window + 1

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]